# How to Remove Gaps between HTML Elements while printing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootbox

The HTML file attached here is working fine when viewed in browser but when I try to print it, there is a lot of gap between the Element such that each div is going on it's own page. how can I remove those gaps while printing?

the code : [code](https://github.com/Prajapathi/empass/blob/main/index.html)
the hosted site : [sitelink](https://prajapathi.github.io/empass/)

You can check the problem by going into sitelink mentioned above and pressing `ctrl + p`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add `float:left;` in your css classes:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  div.nospace {
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
  }
</style>
```

When creating your div, use class="nospace"

```
<div class="nospace">first div</div>
<div class="nospace">second div</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sir Plz check this answer on that page. It would help you how can we remove space between HTML elements. In this article, everything is provided in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements)

you can solve problem buy adding small css property

```
font-size: 0;
```